# Using JSPlumb in an angular.js directive

Tags: angularjs, jsplumb

I'm trying to use jsPlumb along with AngularJS and have run into some problems.  I started with the jsplumb-ng example from github and attempted to modify the jsPlumb parameters to mimic the statemachine demo from the jsPlumb site. The jsplumb-ng approach creates a jsPlumbCanvas directive and it contains jsPlumbNodes.  As a starting point I tried to place some static nodes from the statemachine demo and then add in two nodes controlled by the angular controller.  The demo nodes are placed on the canvas correctly and connections are created.  The angular nodes are created and jsPlumb has trouble in the makeTarget method and prints messages to the console.

*TypeError: Cannot set property '_jsPlumbTarget' of undefined {stack: (...), message: "Cannot set property '_jsPlumbTarget' of undefined"}*

I would greatly appreciate any advice to get moving forward again!

Apologize up front because I'm dancing around the fact that I do not have enough reputation to post images of the problem.

i.imgur.com/Ao4qzm9.png
i.imgur.com/OMS0FGE.png

[Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/zVvsSstIjOoVmk3cHmQj?p=preview)

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.1" data-semver="3.3.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/css/jsplumb.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.14"></script>
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script data-require="bootstrap@3.3.1" data-semver="3.3.1" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    <script data-require="jsplumb@*" data-semver="1.7.3" src="https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/js/jquery.jsPlumb-1.7.3-min.js"></script>

    <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="DiagramEditorCtrl">

<div id="diagramView" style="overflow: hidden;" ng-cloak>

      <js-plumb-canvas
      on-connection="onConnection1"
      x="posx"
      y="posy"
      zoom="zoomlevel"
      ng-drop="true"
      ng-drop-success="onDropComplete1($data,$event)"
      >

      <div ng-repeat="state in stateObjects track by state.uuid">
        <js-plumb-node state-object="state" style="positon: relative;"></js-plumb-node>
      </div>

      <js-plumb-connection ng-click="setActiveConnection($index)" ng-repeat="connection in stateConnections" ng-model="connection">
      </js-plumb-connection>
    </js-plumb-canvas>

</div>
  </body>

</html>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('DiagramEditorCtrl', ['$scope',
function($scope) {

  $scope.zoomlevel = 85;
  $scope.posx = 14;
  $scope.posy = 14;

  $scope.stateObjects = [{
    'name': 'jsPlumb',
    'uuid': '123',
    'style': '',
    'x': 300,
    'y': 150
  }, {
    'name': 'Brewer',
    'uuid': '124',
    'style': '',
    'x': 45,
    'y': 175
  }
];


// Defaults the connections between objects.  Will come from a service.
$scope.stateConnections = [
  // {
  //    targetUUID: 'ds1',
  //    sourceUUID: 'sn1'
  // }

];

var instance = jsPlumb.instance;


$scope.onConnection = function(instance, connection, targetUUID,
  sourceUUID) {
    $scope.stateConnections.push({
      'targetUUID': targetUUID,
      'sourceUUID': sourceUUID,
      'conn': connection
    });
    $scope.$apply();

  };

}
])

.directive('jsPlumbCanvas', function() {
  var jsPlumbZoomCanvas = function(instance, zoom, el, transformOrigin) {
    transformOrigin = transformOrigin || [0, 0];
    var p = ['webkit', 'moz', 'ms', 'o'],
    s = 'scale(' + zoom + ')',
    oString = (transformOrigin[0] * 100) + '% ' + (transformOrigin[1] *
      100) +
      '%';
      for (var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
        el.style[p[i] + 'Transform'] = s;
        el.style[p[i] + 'TransformOrigin'] = oString;
      }
      el.style.transform = s;
      el.style.transformOrigin = oString;
      instance.setZoom(zoom);
    };

    var def = {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        onConnection: '=onConnection',
        zoom: '=',
        x: '=',
        y: '='
      },
      controller: function($scope) {
        this.scope = $scope;
      },
      transclude: true,
      templateUrl: 'workspace.html',



      link: function(scope, element, attr) {


        angular.element(document).ready(function () {


          var instance = jsPlumb.getInstance({
            Endpoint : ['Dot', {radius:2}],
            HoverPaintStyle : {strokeStyle:'#1e8151', lineWidth:2 },
            ConnectionOverlays : [
              [ 'Arrow', {
                location:1,
                id:'arrow',
                length:14,
                foldback:0.8
              } ],
              [ 'Label', { label:'Connecting...', id:'label', cssClass:'aLabel' }]
            ],
            Container:'workspace-container'
          });
          scope.jsPlumbInstance = instance;


          /*
          * Standard JSPlumb Statemachine example that works fine.
          */

          var windows = jsPlumb.getSelector('.workspace-container .node');


          instance.draggable(windows);
          instance.bind('click', function(c) {
            instance.detach(c);
          });

          instance.bind('connection', function(info) {
            info.connection.getOverlay('label').setLabel(info.connection.id);
          });

          instance.doWhileSuspended(function() {
            var isFilterSupported = instance.isDragFilterSupported();
            if (isFilterSupported) {
              instance.makeSource(windows, {
                filter:'.ep',
                anchor:'Continuous',
                connector:[ 'StateMachine', { curviness:20 } ],
                connectorStyle:{ strokeStyle:'#5c96bc', lineWidth:2, outlineColor:'transparent', outlineWidth:4 },
                maxConnections:5,
                onMaxConnections:function(info, e) {
                  alert('Maximum connections (' + info.maxConnections + ') reached');
                }
              });
            }
            else {
              var eps = jsPlumb.getSelector('.ep');
              for (var i = 0; i < eps.length; i++) {
                var e = eps[i], p = e.parentNode;
                instance.makeSource(e, {
                  parent:p,
                  anchor:'Continuous',
                  connector:[ 'StateMachine', { curviness:20 } ],
                  connectorStyle:{ strokeStyle:'#5c96bc',lineWidth:2, outlineColor:'transparent', outlineWidth:4 },
                  maxConnections:5,
                  onMaxConnections:function(info, e) {
                    alert('Maximum connections (' + info.maxConnections + ') reached');
                  }
                });
              }
            }
          });


          instance.makeTarget(windows, {
            dropOptions:{ hoverClass:'dragHover' },
            anchor:'Continuous',
            allowLoopback:true
          });



          instance.connect({ source:'opened', target:'phone1' });
          instance.connect({ source:'phone1', target:'phone1' });


          jsPlumb.fire('jsPlumbDemoLoaded', instance);


          /*
          * End standard JSPlumb statemachine example
          */
        });
      }


    };

    return def;
  })

  .directive('jsPlumbNode', function() {
    var def = {
      restrict: 'E',
      require: '^jsPlumbCanvas',
      scope: {
        node: '=stateObject'
      },

      // At one point, I tried to have a real uuid assigned as the div#id, but
      // JSPlumb seemed to see {{node.uuid}}
      // id="{{node.uuid}}"
      template: '<div class="node" ' +
      ' ng-style="{ \'left\':node.x, \'top\':node.y }" >' +
      '  <div id="ds1-nh" class="node-header" ></div>' +
      '  <div id="ds1-nb" class="node-body">' +
      '{{node.name}}' +
      '  </div>' +
      '  <div id="ds1-nt" class="node-tools">' +
      '    <div id="ds1-nt-o" class="node-tool-options">' +
      '      <span ng-click="configure($index)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>' +
      '    </div>' +
      '    <div id="ds1-nt-d" class="node-tool-delete">' +
      '      <span ng-click="trash($index)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>' +
      '    </div>' +
      '  </div>' +
      '</div>',
      link: function($scope, element, attrs, jsPlumbCanvas) {

        // removed dependence on uuid4 for this plunker.
        $scope.node.uuid = '1234-123-1233';

        angular.element(document).ready(function () {

          var instance = jsPlumbCanvas.scope.jsPlumbInstance;



          function displayMaxConnectionError(info, e) {
            alert('Maximum connections (' + info.maxConnections +
            ') reached');
          }

          var nodeEl = element.find('.node' );


          instance.draggable( nodeEl, {
            grid: [20, 20],
            drag: function(event, ui) {
              var posX, posY;
              if( typeof event.pos !== 'undefined') {
                posX = event.pos[0];
                posY = event.pos[1];
              }
              if (typeof ui !== 'undefined') {
                posX = ui.position.left;
                posY = ui.position.top;
              }
              $scope.node.x = posX;
              $scope.node.y = posY;
              $scope.$apply();
            }
          });


          // suspend drawing and initialise.
          instance.doWhileSuspended(function() {
            var eps =  element.find('.node-header');
            //console.log(eps);

            for (var i = 0; i < eps.length; i++) {
              var e = eps[i],
              p = e.parentNode;
              console.log( 'e: %o', e );
              console.log( 'e.parent: %o', p );
              instance.makeSource(e, {
                parent: p,
                anchor: 'Continuous',
                connector: ['StateMachine', {
                  curviness: 20
                }],
                connectorStyle: {
                  strokeStyle: '#5c96bc',
                  lineWidth: 2,
                  outlineColor: 'transparent',
                  outlineWidth: 4
                },
                maxConnections: 5,
                onMaxConnections: displayMaxConnectionError
              });
            }



            instance.makeTarget(nodeEl, {
              dropOptions: {
                hoverClass: 'dragHover'
              },
              anchor: 'Continuous',

              allowLoopback: true
            });
          });

        });
      }
    };
    return def;
  })






  .directive('jsPlumbConnection', function($timeout) {

    var def = {
      restrict: 'E',
      require: '^jsPlumbCanvas',
      scope: {
        ngClick: '&ngClick',
        ngModel: '=ngModel'
      },
      link: function($scope, element, attrs, jsPlumbCanvas) {
        var instance = jsPlumbCanvas.scope.jsPlumbInstance;


        $timeout(function() {

          if (typeof $scope.ngModel.conn === 'undefined') {

            $scope.ngModel.conn = instance.connect({
              uuids: [
                $scope.ngModel.targetUUID,
                $scope.ngModel.sourceUUID
              ],
              overlays: [
                ['Label', {
                  label: '',
                  id: 'label'
                }]
              ],
              editable: true
            });
          }

          var connection = $scope.ngModel.conn;


          connection.bind('mouseenter', function(conn, originalEvent) {
            $scope.ngModel.mouseover = true;
            $scope.$apply();
          });
          connection.bind('mouseleave', function(conn, originalEvent) {

            $scope.ngModel.mouseover = false;
            $scope.$apply();
          });


        }, 1300);


        $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
          instance.detach($scope.ngModel.conn);
        });

      }
    };
    return def;
  })

  ;
```

I have also looked at the mrquincle/jsplumb-example from github.  It works fine until I tried to load a more recent copy of jsPlumb, jquery, jquery-ui and angular.  The issue with the updated libraries is that the connections are not attached between the two nodes.

i.imgur.com/VLtjWFy.png

[Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/FYJ6Y3TznRvwnz7AgBRh?p=preview)

I am not tied to either the jsplumb-ng or the jsplumb-example approach.  I'm just trying to get one to work.

Thanks ahead of time!